# Removing all instances of [] and ' ' from files

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have text file with the following content:

```
Hi, my name is 'James'. What is your [name]
```

I wont to remove the ' ' and the [] from the text so the output looks like this:

```
Hi, my name is James. What is your name
```

Here is my code:

```
s=  Hi, my name is 'James'. What is your [name]
s=s.replace("[","")
s=s.replace("'","")
```

However the output leave a bracket to the right of name:

```
Hi, my name is James. What is your name]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to replace the right bracket character: `s=s.replace("]","")`.

Comment: You can also use a regex and re.sub to replace the characters @JamesDavinport

Comment: What about a string like `My name isn't 'James'.`. Should the first single quotation mark be removed as well?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to replace `]` in your original code. You can also chain replace statements together

```
In [2]: s=  "Hi, my name is 'James'. What is your [name]"                                                                                                                              

In [3]: s = s.replace("'",'').replace("[","").replace("]","")                                                                                                                          

In [4]: s                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: 'Hi, my name is James. What is your name'
```

Or you can use a regex to strip of `[]` and `'` using the regex `[\[\]\']`, which essentially replaces the characters `[]'` when found in the string with an empty character using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

s = "Hi, my name is 'James'. What is your [name]"
out = re.sub(r"[\[\]\']", "",s)
print(out)
```

The output will be

```
Hi, my name is James. What is your name
```

Answer (score -2):

if your trying to just put this in console or terminal then print("Hi, my name is James. What is your name? ") will work just fine 
But if you are looking  for a person to 'talk' and respond then use an input like,
input('Hi, my name is James. What is your name ')
the user can then type after this and if you use a variable you can respond to the users response
example

name = input('whats your name'? )
print('Hi' + name + 'How are you'? )

putting spaces after question marks will make the code look better(in my opinion) when being executed.

Comment: ps. you put wont instead of want

Comment: He never uses an `input` so why would you assume he controls the user input? Most commonly people who ask questions like this are reading data from a static source (such as a file, api, or database).  As such just say ("Well don't input that") is not a very good answer.

Comment: i wasn't telling him to input it was a question i asked if he was tring to get an input or simply printing the sentence i'm sorry if i didn't make that clear